# Is there hardware which can prove that data was not read?

Tags: hardware

I am looking for information on hardware. Is it possible for a hardware device to prove that some data was not read? If so, how does work?

I read something about a quantum machine using a polarized atom, but I want to know if they are already a solution with common hardware.

Clarification: I don't want to know if our hardware is capable to read atom orientation (I know it's too expensive for common people). But in our disk which use electricity is it possible to have the same caractérisitc? If someone read the information so the data is alterate just a little to see someone as change it, but don't change the data. Am i clear enough?

Comment: can you clarify your answer? it is hard to understand what it is you want to know.

Comment: You want to know if polarized atoms as a "read bit" are a common method used in computers? No, they are not.

Comment: I have found information about use of quantic in cryptography (in french).
http://www.unige.ch/communication/communiques/2015/CdP150209.html

Comment: Less quantum: store a data key in a HSM with a use counter. Encrypt data with this key. Allow any person access to the key and therefore to decrypt the data. Poll the HSM to see if the counter was increased. This doesn't do what you want on a physical level, but it may suffice in practice. Note that once data is read it can be copied indefinitely.